# Node data format of class hierarchy in OWL by OWLAPI

Tags: java, owl-api

I'd like to extract all the class nodes in an OWL ontology, and the class nodes are written as the following format:

```
[{
   name: node1
   children: [{
       name: node11
      },
      {name: node12,
       children: [{
              name:node121,
              name:node122
      }]
}]
}]
```

I use printHierachy method to extract the class hierarchy structure, but how to transfer the structure to the above format?

Answer (score 0):

You should `override` toString method for `Node` object:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(  );

    builder.append( "{ name: "  );
    builder.append( this.name  );

    builder.append( ", children: [ " );
    if(this.children != null ) {
        for ( Node n : this.children ) {
            builder.append( n.toString() + ", " );
        }
    }
    builder.append( " ] }" );
    return builder.toString();

}
```

Comment: Should I define the node object like: public class TreeNode{ private String treenodeName, private ArrayList<TreeNode> ChildrenNode}?

Comment: @yuan yes object should be define